# Glide is not loading drawables into view

Tags: android, android-glide

I've just updated my glide's version to 4.6.0 from 3.7.0 for better performance . In 3.7.0 it was loading image from drawable resources without any problem but after updating it's showing error  while loading drawables. I also tried to find similar issues in SO and github but none of them could solve my issue.

Error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifBitmapProvider
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.ByteBufferGifDecoder.<init>(ByteBufferGifDecoder.java:70)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.ByteBufferGifDecoder.<init>(ByteBufferGifDecoder.java:56)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.<init>(Glide.java:339)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder.build(GlideBuilder.java:472)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:264)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:219)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:180)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:164)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:670)
                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:747)
                                                                    at layout.login.onCreateView(login.java:78)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1655)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1390)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1650)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1906)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3698)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:350)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                    at community.infinity.Login_Page.onCreate(Login_Page.java:60)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code  :

```
 Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.tag).into(imgView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used glide-full-4.4.0.jar(https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/download/v4.4.0/glide-full-4.4.0.jar) directly, and solved this problem.

Comment: sir after adding that .jar now it's showing **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Srinu\Infinity\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Srinu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.bumptech.glide\glide\3.6.1\86b122e640af09b0723e1fa44083c354ba6d9089\glide-3.6.1.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [glide-3.6.1.jar:com/bumptech/glide/gifdecoder/GifDecoder.class]))**